How to render non-latin characters in chrome-php on Almalinux system when browser is running in headless mode?
Non-Latin characters are showing as boxes or not showing at all when text in rendered in headless chromium running via Chrome-Php on AlmaLinux OS as seen below:

The characters show as intended when the webpage is opened in Chrome on Windows/Android/iOS. How to resolve this issue?
